# Can appengine-application.xml be generated?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

The Google App Engine documentation for modules (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration) describes a few .xml files.  Is there a way to generate all of these files with Maven?

Some of the files seem like they have to be manually created, particularly appengine-application.xml and application.xml.  Is that true or can I use Maven somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But see this to [create an AppEngine project with Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating)

It explains how to use the App Engine-provided Maven App Engine artifact called appengine-skeleton-archetype to create a new project.

Then, configure your application using the generated file called src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Full documentation on using Maven is at [Using Apache Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) which has a better link to [Configuring appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig)

To generate the files with Maven, see [this blog on the process](http://akshayrangnekar.github.io/blog/2014/03/14/up-and-running-on-appengine-with-maven-jersey-and-guice-part-2/)  Note: it appears the archetypes at the Maven Central repo have been updated to 2.0.0-1.9.10, so the part of the archetype being outdate can be ignored.

To install a project that already has appengine-application.xml or application.xml files created, see this [sample as a template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java)  Look for them under:

`appengine-modules-sample-java / appengine-modules-ear / src / main / application / META-INF`

Comment: the Maven App Engine artifact appengine-skeleton-archetype seems to generate some but not all of the .xml files required for modules (as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration).  Some of the files seem like they have to be manually created, particularly appengine-application.xml and application.xml. Is that true or can I use Maven somehow?

Comment: Thx @user1258245. Thanks for pointing out the Maven repo has been updated. However the whole set of Maven paremters on Akshay's blog are different from the Using Apache Maven link. The blog says `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.appengine.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appengine-skeleton-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.8.7 -DgroupId=com.listerly.server -DartifactId=server -Dversion=0.1 -Dpackage=com.listerly` but Google says `mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.14 -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype`

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky Either way, I don't see Maven generating more than just a basic config file that needs to be edited anyway.

Comment: Thx @user1258245. Google [modules docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration) say to put `application.xml` in `app/META-INF` but the [sample as a template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java) has it in `appengine-modules-sample-java/appengine-modules-ear/src/main/application/META-INF`. How come?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky It's configured to use a maven plugin https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/  see appengine-modules-sample-java/appengine-modules-ear/pom.xml The application.xml is configured in the <plugin>... <applicationXml>

Comment: I may have figured out the answer by reading about J2EE and Maven.  I guess the [Google modules docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration) describe a [J2EE packaged application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Overview5.html).

Comment: Thanks @user1258245, I must have just figured that out while you were typing.  The [sample as a template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java) also uses Gradle. I'm not knowledgeable enough yet to know what it uses Gradle vs. Maven for. Do you think I can leave their Gradle stuff out or is it integral somehow?  Thank you.

Comment: Here's what worked for me.  I deleted the string `maven` from `maven-application.xml` in [pom.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-ear/pom.xml). Then I removed [application.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/application.xml) and replaced it with [maven-application.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/maven-application.xml).

Comment: if you can change your answer to "No" in response to my original question (can appengine-application.xml be generated), I'll accept your answer.