# How morph Maven-generated GAE skeleton into a 2-module application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to reconcile these two sets of directions in order to create a 2 module Google App Engine project:

1] Directions for generating a Google App Engine directory structure with Maven (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#creating_app_engine_applications_or_backend_apis_using_the_archetypes)

2] Google App Engine modules configuration (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration)

A simple issue is where to put a module's appengine-web.xml?

Document 1 says to run this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.14 -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype
```

And the result is a structure like this:

[image: Result of using Maven to generate appengine-skeleton-archetype artifact]

Notice the location of the appengine-web.xml for what is presumably the `default` module:

```
/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

Now if I want to turn this Maven-generated 1-module structure into a 2-module structure, Document 2 says I will need a directory structure like this:

[image: Two-module unpacked Java Enterprise Archive (EAR) directory structure]

So it looks like the default module's appengine-web.xml file needs to be moved to:

```
/myapp/module1/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

Am I correctly interpreting the directions for Document 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image for Document 1 describes the source directory whereas the image in Document 2 describes the target directory.

The terms *source* and *target* pertain to conventional directories in Maven.

Since Document 1's instructions for generating a skeletal Google App Engine project do describe how to add Google Modules, the application.xml and appengine-application.xml files have to be placed in the conventional location where Maven would look for them, namely the *source* directory here:

`/<module1>/src/main/application/META-INF/application.xml`

See also the following questions for an example:

- [What is a maven-application.xml file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664888/what-is-a-maven-application-xml-file-for/26719082#26719082)
- [Can appengine-application.xml be generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557828/can-appengine-application-xml-be-generated)